# LessCss - Creating themes (aka css files that use different variables)

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following file structure:

- main.less
- modules

  - colors.less
  - header.less
  - footer.less
  - video_player.less
  - reset.less
  - base.less

---

`colors.less` looks like:

```
@brand-primary-color: orange;
@brand-secondary-color: grey;
```

---

I would like to import `colors.less` in `main.less`, and have the variables used globally throughout the less files.

Creating themes would look something like this:

- brand-1.less

  `@import "themes/brand-1-colors.less"`
- brqand-2.less

  `@import "themes/brand-2-colors.less"`
- brand-3.less

  `@import "themes/brand-3-colors.less"`
- [...]

---

Can't find any way to do this!

The only method that seems to work is to import the `colors.less` file within **each** less sub-file. This makes creating themes a bit tedious...

---

Any ideas? :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Presuming `main.less` has CSS in it, all you have to do is create a file where you'd import all other `less` files. The file structure would look like:

- final.less

  - modules

    - main.less
    - colors.less
    - header.less
    - footer.less
    - video_player.less
    - reset.less
    - base.less

After compiled, the `final.css` would be the CSS file containing everything. The `final.less` would look like:

```
@import "main.less";
@import "colors.less";
@import "header.less";
@import "footer.less";
@import "video-player.less";
@import "reset.less";
@import "reset.less";
```

Last but not least, you should compile only `final.less`.